# Scala Replacement by Regex

Tags: regex, scala, replace

I've a string like

```
val bar = "M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo".
```

Now I split this string and define the pattern

```
val split = bar.split("-")
val pattern = ".*(A|K)\\d.*".r
```

and now I want to replace A9K9foo in the last entry of 'split'

```
val last = split.last
val suffix = last match {
  case pattern(_) => last replaceFirst ("""(A\d)?(K\d)?.*""", "")
  case _          => last
}
```

What I know is that replaceFirst is executed but it won't replace A9K9foo in my 'last' val
(replaceFirst should only executed if 'last' matches 'pattern'), the wanted result is M2.

Edit: It could happen that last is not M9A9K9foo but M9A9 or M9K9foo or maybe M9A9K9. All i want is to replace all content except the text before A\d or K\d but if there is no A\d or K\d nothing should happen.

Do you know why this replacement won't work?

Comment: Very weird thing to want to do, could you provide more context, we may be able to suggest a completely alternative way - hopefully one that avoids regex! :)

Comment: there is no more context, I want just the M9 string everytime

Answer (score 0):

You're using String.replaceFirst, and your pattern has a wildcard that consumes everything.

Maybe you want:

```
last replaceFirst ("""A\dK\d""", "")
```

where the A9K9 is not optional, and that's all you want to replace.

There are other formulations:

```
scala> val r = """(A\dK\d)""".r
r: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = (A\dK\d)

scala> val m = (r findAllMatchIn bar).toList.last
m: scala.util.matching.Regex.Match = A9K9

scala> s"${m.before}${m.after}"
res15: String = M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9foo
```

That's not the most clever.

More:

```
scala> val r = """(A|K)\d""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = (A|K)\d

scala> val bar = "M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo"
bar: String = M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo-M9A9K9foo

scala> val last = (bar split "-").last
last: String = M9A9K9foo

scala> r findFirstMatchIn last map (_.before) getOrElse last
res0: CharSequence = M9

scala> val r = """(.*?)((A|K)\d.*)?""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = (.*?)((A|K)\d.*)?

scala> last match { case r(prefix, _*) => prefix }
res1: String = M9

scala> "M9" match { case r(prefix, _*) => prefix }
res2: String = M9

scala> "M9K9foo" match { case r(prefix, _*) => prefix }
res3: String = M9

scala> val r = """(.*?)(?:(?:A|K)\d.*)?""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = (.*?)(?:(?:A|K)\d.*)?

scala> last match { case r(prefix) => prefix }
res4: String = M9
```

The diagnosis is the same; there are different ways to pull the string apart.

Comment: A\d and K\d are optional. M9A9K9foo could also be M9A9foo or M9K9foo or M9A9K9. But if it is just M9, nothing should replaced.

And whats the problem with replaceFirst?
I want to replace the first A9 or K9 and any text behind and not matching M9

Comment: Nothing is wrong with replaceFirst, but it is Java API per se. I've shown you a few options. Take it or leave it, etc. Not brain surgery.